# how do i display an image on text view using ibm watson assistant?

Tags: android-studio, textview, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a chat application using IBM Watson assistant and android studio. The problem is I'm having difficulties with displaying images in a text view.

I have added the image as URL Image. It is displaying and working in the try console as well. See the screenshot below.

[image]

But when I try displaying it in my android app it won't show up...

Following is my XML, display code for responses,

```
 Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
        message.setMessage(message.getMessage());
((ViewHolder) holder).message.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.getMessage()));

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bubble_bot"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textIsSelectable="true
        android:textSize="14sp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your Watson api version so that in watson responses you will get the response type field where you can extract the image